# scp showing permission denied but ssh is working

Tags: ssh, scp

`scp` command is failing saying "Permission Denied" but `ssh` command is working. Also, I am able to create new file in same folder.

Windows OS using MINGW

Following is `scp` command log

```
scp -vv ./dist/txt/test.txt 123.123.123.123:/dist/web/server/files/A123/txt

Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host 123.123.123.123, user (unspecified), command scp -v -t /dist/web/server/files/A123/txt

OpenSSH_7.6p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  10 Dec 2017

debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config

debug2: resolving "123.123.123.123" port 22

debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0

debug1: Connecting to 123.123.123.123 [123.123.123.123] port 22.

debug1: Connection established.

debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory

debug1: identity file /c/Users/james.bond/.ssh/id_rsa type -1

debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory

debug1: identity file /c/Users/james.bond/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1

debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory

debug1: identity file /c/Users/james.bond/.ssh/id_dsa type -1

debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory

debug1: identity file /c/Users/james.bond/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1

debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory

debug1: identity file /c/Users/james.bond/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1

debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory

debug1: identity file /c/Users/james.bond/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1

debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory

debug1: identity file /c/Users/james.bond/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1

debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory

debug1: identity file /c/Users/james.bond/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1

debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6

debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4

debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000

debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK

debug1: Authenticating to 123.123.123.123:22 as 'james.bond'

debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent

debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received

debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal

debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c

debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa

debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc

debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc

debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1

debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1

debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib

debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib

debug2: languages ctos:

debug2: languages stoc:

debug2: first_kex_follows 0

debug2: reserved 0

debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal

debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256

debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256

debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr

debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr

debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1

debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1

debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com

debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com

debug2: languages ctos:

debug2: languages stoc:

debug2: first_kex_follows 0

debug2: reserved 0

debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256

debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256

debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64-etm@openssh.com compression: none

debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64-etm@openssh.com compression: none

debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY

debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:m11RFE/zz7zxOVVktwI5Yv1+oXhfZ18iN8YQ2ms

debug1: Host '123.123.123.123' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.

debug1: Found key in /c/Users/james.bond/.ssh/known_hosts:1

debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1

debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks

debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent

debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS

debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received

debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0

debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks

debug2: key: /c/Users/james.bond/.ssh/id_rsa (0x0)

debug2: key: /c/Users/james.bond/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0)

debug2: key: /c/Users/james.bond/.ssh/id_ecdsa (0x0)

debug2: key: /c/Users/james.bond/.ssh/id_ed25519 (0x0)

debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received

debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>

debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth

debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received

NOTICE TO USERS

-----------------

Warning.

 

debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey

debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/james.bond/.ssh/id_rsa

Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/james.bond/.ssh/id_rsa':

debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply

debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic

debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/james.bond/.ssh/id_dsa

debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/james.bond/.ssh/id_ecdsa

debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/james.bond/.ssh/id_ed25519

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method

debug1: No more authentication methods to try.

james.bond@123.123.123.123: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).

lost connection
```